# Removing from a list all but one element of a specific type

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a list and a notion of what it means for two elements to be isomorphic. I would like to create a subset of the list with exactly one representative from each isomorphism class.

The specific case in which I want to apply this is I have a list of graphs, and I would like to remove isomorphic duplicates. I have a very long list of graphs (~100,000) that I would like to apply this to.

Another example:

```
L={6,7,4,3,9,30,4}
```

And my notion of isomorphism is if the numbers are the same mod 3. In this case, an acceptable output would be

```
{6,7}
```

(obviously this is not unique).

What is the most efficient way to do this? For example, one could "greedily" select elements, and at each step compare an element in L with the guys who were already chosen to be part of the output. I don't think this will terminate in a reasonable amount of time in my case.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[{6, 7, 4, 3, 9, 30, 4}, Mod[#, 3] &]`?

Comment: This works in the specific example given but not in the case of a list of graphs and graph isomorphism

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[listOfobjects, yourIsomorphism]` where `yourIsomorphism[obj1, obj2]` is `True` is `obj1` and `obj2` are isomorphic, `False` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `DeleteDuplicates[listOfThings, isomorphicForMeQ]` gives the desired result.

```
SeedRandom[1]
graphs = RandomGraph[UniformGraphDistribution[5, 5], 8];
Grid[Partition[graphs, 4]]
```

[image]

```
Row@DeleteDuplicates[graphs, IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

[image]

Using a made-up graph-isomorphism condition

```
myIsomorphicGraphQ = Equal @@ (Mean[HITSCentrality[#]] & /@ {##}) &;
Row@DeleteDuplicates[graphs, myIsomorphicGraphQ ]
```

[image]